# how to schedule time based loop through Excel sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a dashboard in Excel that connects to database and updates itself every 15 mins. I have already created a scheduler for this using the code below. However, I also want that during that waiting time of 15 minutes, the dashboard keep looping through all sheets showing every sheet for 1 minute. How do I build the second level of schedule into my code?

my_procedure is the macro that connects to database and updates the data in the workbook.

```
Public Sub scheduler_1()
    Call my_procedure
    Call scheduler_2
End Sub

Public Sub scheduler_2()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "scheduler_1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to solve it fairly quickly. I added a loop in the scheduler_2 macro

```
Public Sub scheduler_2()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
    Application.OnTime RunWhen, "scheduler_1"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Do While Now < RunWhen
    Sheet5.Activate
    Call custom_wait(5)
    Sheet3.Activate
    Call custom_wait(5)
Loop

End Sub
```

Where custom_wait macro is:

```
Public Sub custom_wait(ByVal i As Integer)
    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + i
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont see how you are looping through all the sheets, you just have two sheets

Comment: good point. that was just an example, I am now able to do it with some and all sheets depending on the audience of the dashboard. My key concern was not looping as such, but looping while waiting for the next run of the perpetual macro calling.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a scheduler every minute for looping through the sheets and use a `Static Date` variable inside `scheduler_2` to work out when 15 minutes have passed and then run `my_procedure`.